# Weird mysql behavior when adding foreign key

Tags: sql, foreign-keys, mariadb, alter-table

I am trying to add a simple foreign key like so

```
ALTER TABLE `4over4local`.`wf_job_status`
ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_sales_job_status_sales_job1`
  FOREIGN KEY (`job_id`)
  REFERENCES `4over4local`.`sales_job` (`job_id`)
  ON DELETE CASCADE
  ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

But i am getting a very weird error with some database table named `#sql-d74_9` that doesn't even exist.

```
ERROR 1452: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`4over4local`.`#sql-d74_9`, 
CONSTRAINT `fk_sales_job_status_sales_job1` FOREIGN KEY (`job_id`) REFERENCES `sales_job` (`job_id`) 
ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)
```

I have previously made very similar queries and they all worked fine except this one. What could cause this and what i am doing wrong? I am using MariaDB 13

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error indicates that you have rows in the table that do not satisfy the foreign key constraint you are trying to add. You need to fix your data before you can create the constraint.

You can exhibit offending rows with the following query:

```
select wjs.*
from wf_job_status wjs
where not exists (select 1 from sales_job sj where sj.job_id = wjs.job_id)
```